# iOS mobile build debug vs release

Tags: ios

I'm into QA and have received an iOS .ipa file (a test build) to be tested.

Problem: The question is how do I make sure if this iOS build file is a debug build or a release build?

What I have tried: I do not have access to XCode. I have spent hours on the net searching for a relevant answer, to my above problem, but all in vain.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

You can directly mail me if required on: jerry.tom141@yahoo.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you can't check it if developer haven't mentioned that somewhere in application (f.e v1.0 D label text)

Comment: The fastest way would be to ask the person that sent it to you.

Comment: Hi @Injectios I have unzipped this ipa file, do you think this information might be available in the info.plist file>

Comment: See my answer, which is partly a comment: what do you want to know exactly? Debug and release are just names. Do you want to know if debugging symbols were still included, how it was signed, or something else?

Comment: Agreed with amb's answer.  Since, you can only get ipa file from  distribution only including ad-hoc distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's an Ad-Hoc build.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the only way you can know this is check with the developer. In Xcode, the Archive setting is by default set to *Release* mode. If the developer hasn't changed this it will be a *Release* build.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Debug and release are, as far as I know, just names that you can configure. I think you could even them to actually be the opposite. So I remain a bit in the dark about what you want to know exactly.

What may help you is to unpack the IPA. Basically it is a ZIP file, so you can rename it and unzip. Next you could run `codesign -d -vvvv appname.app` which gives you some information about the certificate that was used to sign it. This is important because for development and release different certificates are used. We mention the type of certificate in its name, perhaps your developers do so as well.

Comment: Hi @Jochem, Can i run this command on a windows machine? If yes then  please guide me through.

Comment: No this is a tool for OSX, I can't find